# I cannot create class by JQuery?

Tags: jquery

this code can create class modalNavLink-show
but cannot create class modalNavLink-hidden, please help me master..
this my code on html code script.

```js
if ($('#modalNavLink').attr('class', 'modalNavLink-hidden')) {
  $('#image-open-modalNavLink').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#modalNavLink').attr('class', 'modalNavLink-show');
  });
} else {
  $(window).on("click", function(e) {
    $('#modalNavLink').attr('class', 'modalNavLink-hidden');
  });
}
```

Comment: when/where do you execute this code in your logic? and do you want to append the hidden class where ever you click on the window?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that you're using the setter of `attr()`, of which the result is always a jQuery object which will coerce to `true`, so the logic will only ever go through the first condition. If you want to check a value use the getter; `attr('foo') == 'bar'`. In this case `hasClass('foo')` may be a better and more reliable choice.

However, from the context of the code it appears that you should put the `if` condition *inside* the `click` event handler so that it's evaluated every time the event runs, not just once when the page loads. Taking this a step further you can negate the need for the condition at all and just use `toggleClass()`, as that's what the code achieves.

You will also need to use a delegated event handler as you're dynamically changing the `class` you select by at runtime.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.modalNavLink-show, .modalNavLink-hidden', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('modalNavLink-show modalNavLink-hidden');
});
```

```css
.modalNavLink-show {
  opacity: 1;
}
.modalNavLink-hidden {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modalNavLink-show">Click me</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what that means.